# snmpwalk: Unknown user name (SNMP v3)

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

I'm trying to run SNMP version 3 but I'm getting this error:

```
snmpwalk: Unknown user name (SNMP v3)
```

This is the command I'm using

```
sudo snmpwalk -v3 -u bob -l AuthPriv -a SHA -A bobpassword -x AES -X bobpassword 127.0.0.1
```

I've created the user bob with this command:

```
net-snmp-create-v3-user
```

I created the user bob with the password bobpassword. For some reason it tells me that the user is unknown. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the configuration file (likely to be `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` by default) to see if you do have the user registered?

Comment: @LexLi Yes, it seems like they are registered. I can see "createUser bob MD5 "bobpassword" DES "bobpassword"".

Comment: Then why do you use SHA and AES?

Comment: @grabbhalf ANY UPDATE ON THIS?  Add the solution for future readers, then accept your own answer it fixed the problem.  I would like to know

Comment: @Bwebb I've figured out how it was broken; see my answer to this question. Probably worth bookmarking questions like these to track progress on updates

Answer (score 0):

i find this path.

firsly stop snmtp:

```
systemctl stop snmpd
```

after that create user:

```
net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -A {WRITE SHA PASSWORD} -X {WRITE AES PASSWORD} -a SHA -x AES {WRITE USER NAME}
```

lastly start snmpd service:

```
systemctl restart snmpd
```

For control:

```
snmp-walk -v3 -u {WRITE SNMP USER NAME} -l authPriv -a SHA -A {WRITE SHA PASSWORD} -x AES -X {WRITE AES PASSWORD} {DESTINATION IP}
```

Not: I use SHA and AES encryption. You can use different encryption methots.

Comment: still shows: snmpwalk: Unknown user name

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer:

As I suspected, ***special characters in the passwords were generating the error***- which itself was a red-herring; it was nothing at all to do with an "*unknown user*". The user was not the issue, but rather the password associated with it was borking things...

Note: You have to stop the SNMPD service before executing the `net-snmp-create-v3-user` command:

```
systemctl stop snmpd.service
```

And of course restart it after creating the user.

## What DIDN'T Work:

Passwords using special characters- *even when encased by single quotes*- will generate the error "*snmpwalk: Unknown user name*":

```
sudo net-snmp-create-v3-user -ro -A 'y2VP^^>c3Q]-|"g' -a SHA -X '8:c4ii@!><?::}' -x AES snmpadmin
```

## What DID Work:

Just replace "*AlphaNumericUsingCase*" below with passwords that use letters with upper & lower case and numbers:

```
sudo net-snmp-create-v3-user -ro -A 'AlphaNumericUsingCase' -a SHA -X 'AlphaNumericUsingCase' -x AES snmpadmin
```

From my reading, it also appears that passwords must be a minimum of at least (8) characters in length.

## Conclusion:

Usually encasing special characters in single quotes ***should*** result in them being interpreted as literals, but this clearly was not happening.

I suspect ***some*** special characters will work in the passwords, but that will have to be determined with a bit of trial-n-error. In any event, you should be blocking access to UDP/161 & UDP/162 in your gateway firewall.